# Pjax changes url incorrectly then server error occures

Tags: url, html5-history, pjax

I have two pjax containers on my page, which loaded from different php scripts after base page is loaded from third.

Pjax changes url attributes correctly, until server error occures. Normally it changes only get parameters and other part of url is the same (entire page script) but when error appears it redirects me on page with name of script where error was found.

So my pages are basically `/page?a=1&b=2` but on errors url becomes `/part-of-page1?a=1&b=2` or `/part-of-page2?a=1&b=2`

How can I make it stay the same url?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I added try-catch block catching all possible errors into both partial controllers

So on catching any error I make it show another view with message about error inside main page blocks.

It prevents redirecting on server errors as I asked

In addition you can use next code for prevent changing url on any pjax error (it may be not server errors but something like browsing other page while data is loading)

```
  $(document).on('pjax:error', function(){
      return false;
  });
```

Comment: This answer does not provide enough information to be helpful to other people with the same problem as yours.  Please consider 1) improving the Question to explain the problem better and 2) improving the Answer to explain the solution better.  Alternatively (i.e. if you don't want to do the work), consider deleting both the Q & A.